# Whats more efficient: displaying dynamic HTML or rendering PDF and embedding it

Tags: c#, html, pdf, iframe, itext

I am building a large scale web application with many "print" requests a minute. We have dynamic content from an editor that I print out with other HTML elements. What is more efficient, rendering that html and then printing the html page or rendering a PDF server side and displaying that in an iframe to be printed?

With the multiple server side calls for rendering the images plus authenticating the user (and we also have a dynamic image header and footer dependent on the logged in user) would it be more efficient to render native PDF controls and then put a pdf in an iframe to print?

I was planning on using itext sharp or http://www.websupergoo.com/ for the rendering.

the app is a c# Web forms application.

Comment: The first one. Always. Printing a web page requires no server-side processing.

Comment: However it does require server side processing to render the page because of all the dynamic content that needs to be fetched. Wouldn't rendering the PDF be similar?

Comment: Even if they are equal, you should choose HTML.  Saving off a PDF leads to all kinds of messiness down the road. Storage problems, what if you want to change the report, its now not reflected in the previous pdf's... HTML.. much simpler.

Comment: If having the report look exactly the same across all browsers is of paramount importance, then you can choose PDF.

Comment: @Andrew I had presumed you'd be rendering the HTML either way, otherwise what are your users printing? Either way, rendering HTML will be massively more efficient than dynamically building a PDF. Web application frameworks are optimised for building HTML.

Comment: I agree with @paqogomez's second comment. Ignoring efficiency for a moment (even though that was your question),  do you have need for guaranteed cross-browser stylings of printed content? Do you want absolute control over page breaks? If so, that's one of the reasons why the PDF standard was created. Otherwise you can get "pretty close" with HTML/CSS, especially among the modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it in order to generate the PDF you need to generate the HTML. So by generating the PDF you are adding to the processing required not reducing it.